# NSString to NSDate conversion returns null

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

`NSString` to `NSDate` conversion returns `null`.

The original string outputs "**2013-07-16T18:42:56+02:00**" but when I try to convert to an `NSDate` it returns "null"

Here's my code:

```
// original string
NSString *str = [timeStamp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

// convert to date
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

//[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'+11:00'"];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"]; // updated from Stavash's post below. Still null is outputted for the date though
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Australia/Melbourne"]];
NSDate *dte = [dateFormat dateFromString:str];

cell.timeStampLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dte ];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why have you hard coded +11:00 into the format? I think this will work for you (on iOS6.0+):

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"];
```

For iOS5.0+ use:

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ssZZZ"];
```

---

**Update**

See Rob's comments below - on iOS5.0+ the date format will only work on the timezone without a colon.

Comment: thank you. I changed that and yet the output is still "null". this NSString *str = [timeStamp objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; outputs 2013-07-16T18:42:56+02:00 so I know that the string is ok and it's just the conversion.

Comment: The `ZZZZZ` is for iOS6 and above.

Comment: Sorry, was missing escapes. See edited answer + Rob's remark. Use ZZZ for iOS 5.0 +

Comment: Also `YYYY` should be `yyyy`, http://cldr.unicode.org/translation/date-time. And sine you are passing the time zone in the date string you do not need to set the local. This is only handy when you want to print in the date.Just remove the `:` from the time zone in the string and use `Z` this will work on most iOS versions.

Comment: As far as I know, `ZZZ` expects the time zone as `+0200` without colon.

Comment: @MartinR So what's the alternative? Can't find one with colon.

Comment: @Stavash: I don't think there is an alternative. See rckoenes comment above: You have to remove to colon manually.

Comment: @MartinR Agreed. In iOS 5, colon has to be removed. In iOS 6, you can use `ZZZZZ`.

Comment: @Rob Isn't it weird that iOS 5 format isn't able to support a certain format? Isn't there a workaround?

Comment: @Stavash: See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW13: iOS 5 and iOS 6 implement different versions of the Unicode standard. ZZZZZ for the ISO8601 time zone format is new in version tr35-25, and not covered in version tr35-19.

Comment: @Stavash It's especially weird because ISO8601/RFC3339 date format predates iOS5 significantly. Still, if you need iOS5 support, I think you have to do that clumsy edit of the date string first.

Comment: Thanks @Rob for clarifying. I've edited my answer to include what we've summed up.

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying date in incorrect manner

corrected code is written below

```
NSString *str = @"2013-07-16T18:42:56+0200";
// convert to date
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"];    [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Australia/Melbourne"]];
NSDate *dte = [dateFormat dateFromString:str];
```

Comment: He has a colon in the timezone. Sadly, it makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Australia/Melbourne"]];

NSString *dateString = @"2013-07-16T18:42:56+02:00";
NSArray * dateArray = [dateString componentsSeparatedByString:@"+"];
NSString * timeZone = [dateArray lastObject];
timeZone = [timeZone stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@""];
dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@+%@",[dateArray objectAtIndex:0], timeZone];

NSDate *dte = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
```

try this... hope it works for you.. the main reason why I have done this is ZZZ will understand +0200, it wont understand +02:00. in order to make DateFormatter understand +02:00 we need to use TZD, which is also resulting null unfortunately :( reference :http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime